# JQuery validate custom error message is not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Following is the form validation javascript in my application:

```
$('#EmploymentHistoryForm').validate({
ignore: ':hidden, [readonly=readonly]',
rules: {
    'MemberJob.Phone': {
        PhoneFieldValidation: true
    }
},
messages: {
    'MemberJob.Phone': {
        PhoneFieldValidation: $.viewUrl.url.invaliedPhoneMessage
    }
},
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
    ShowErrors(errorMap, errorList, this.validElements());
},
submitHandler: function (form, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
});
```

Here, $.viewUrl.url.invaliedPhoneMessage is set at the cshtml page (in ASP.NET MVC), and while debugging the javascript I can see proper value in that variable when $('...').validate function gets hit.

I have registered a new validator "PhoneFieldValidation" in JQuery validators collection:

```
$.validator.addMethod("PhoneFieldValidation", ValidatePhoneAndAltPhone);
```

Following is the rendered HTML for the input control for which I have added this validation rule:

```
<input class="PhoneFieldValidation" id="MemberJob_Phone" name="MemberJob.Phone" type="text" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

I can see the validation getting fired correctly. That means, "ValidatePhoneAndAltPhone" method is getting called, and returning a boolean result based on the input.

However, the error message is not getting displayed properly. It displays "Warning: No message defined for MemberJob.Phone" instead of "Invalid Phone Number".

While debugging through customMessage function of jquery.validate.js, I could see "this.settings.messages" collection is not having the message for "MemberJob.Phone" field, and that looks to be the root cause of this issue.

Any idea of how to resolve this issue?

I know we can add "data-msg-[rulename]" attribute in the HTML tag which will fix the issue. But I am sure the current approach I am following is also correct. Seems I am missing something.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You never mention where `$.viewUrl.url.invaliedPhoneMessage` comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never mentioned where `$.viewUrl.url.invaliedPhoneMessage` comes from.

If there is already a message defined in your custom `PhoneFieldValidation` method, then you would not define a message within the `messages` object.

<s>Otherwise, you cannot use a JavaScript variable within the `messages` object without a function.</s>

The whole problem is being caused by the Unobtrusive plugin which is automatically constructing the `.validate()` method call.  You cannot call `.validate()` more than once on the same `form`; and all subsequent calls are ignored.  Instead, you can simply define the custom message for `PhoneFieldValidation` within its `.addMethod()` method.

```
$.validator.addMethod("PhoneFieldValidation", function(value, element) {
    // your custom method function here;
}, "This is your custom validation error message");
```

Comment: I have updated question to mention the source of $.viewUrl.url.invaliedPhoneMessage. However, as I can see expected value in that variable while debugging, it doesn't seem to be an issue there.

Comment: As of now, I have found one solution, and that is to pass the message in $.validator.addMethod() function, and it works. But I am still clueless of why the message specified in the "messages" segment doesn't work.

Comment: @Nirman, it does not matter how the page is constructed or what's on the server; JavaScript only cares about the final rendered code as seen within the browser source.  Inspect the DOM and look at what is inside the `messages` object.

Comment: @Nirman, you also never mentioned ASP until now.  Are you using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin?  If so, then you cannot construct `.validate()` yourself... it will NOT override the instance of `.validate()` constructed by the Unobtrusive plugin.

Comment: Oh sorry.. actually, I thought it doesn't have anything to do with ASP.NET MVC so I didn't mention in the question. But yes, I added a tag for ASP.NET MVC, but a moderator deleted it! You mean to say, that $('#EmployementHistoryForm').validate(..) cannot work if we have unobtrusive validation plugin? I have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax plugin loaded in this page. Does it causing the issue?

Comment: I tried replicating the same code in a new ASP.NET MVC application, wherein I have loaded jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js plugin. But it is working properly there, and also showing proper message. In that case, it would mean, the issue is when jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is used alongside .validate()

Comment: @Nirman, yes, if you have Unobtrusive Validation plugin you cannot call the `.validate()` method.  Only **one** instance of `.validate()` can be used at a time and once it's called by Unobtrusive, all subsequent calls, including yours, are always ignored.

Comment: @Nirman, AFAIK, you can't use Unobtrusive Ajax without having Unobtrusive Validation in place.  Right?

Comment: yes I agree. the page where I was facing the issue is having both jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js script files. However, the one which was working seemlessly had only jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js. But I got your point, if we have unobtrusive validation plugin then we cannot call .validate(). In such cases, the option is to specify the rule and message both in $.validator.addMethod() function. Thanks for your help and clarifying my concepts. I am marking this as an answer with a little edit. Feel free to correct the same if you find any discrepancies :)